# Qt driver for PostgreSQL compilation error

Tags: qt, postgresql, compiler-errors

When compiling psql with following command:

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\include" "LIBS+=D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib\libpq.lib" psql.pro
make
```

I got following message:

```
... g++: Files\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib -Lc:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib tmp\obj\debug_shared\qsqlpsqld_resource_res.o D:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib\libpq.lib -lQtSqld4 -lQtCored4 : Invalid argument  
make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlpsqld4.dll] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/2010.05/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql'  
make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

Replacement D:\Program Files -> D:\Progra~1 doesn't change anything. How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands should be:

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=D:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\include" "LIBS+=D:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib\libpq.lib" psql.pro
```

then it is needed to manually fix Makefiles (Debug and Release) to exclude all occurencies of space in dirname, then run

```
make
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes in the qmake invocation. If that fails, try using forward slashes instead of backslashes in the path.